# Tar Jenkins jobs build logs and send to S3

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have lot of jenkins jobs builders folder in various hierarchy places like this

I need to collect all sub-folders within builds folder from each job and tar it keeping the path to these jobs intact (i.e. when i tar it and extract i will ensure it will land on jobs/test1/builds etc.

What is the best way to approach this?

```
/var/lib/jenkins/folder1
├── config.xml
└── jobs
  └── test1
    ├── builds
    ├── 1

/var/lib/jenkins/folder2
├── config.xml
└── jobs
  └── awsbuild
    ├── jobs
      ├── developers
        ├── jobs
         ├── billing
          ├── branches
           ├── testbranch
            ├── builds
             ├── 1
```

Comment: tar czf my_jenkins.tar.gz /var/lib/jenkins/    (or parse if you don't want the root items)
Then to unpack: tar -zxf my_jenkins.tar.gz

Comment: But i only want to tar the build folder. Not everything. And when i untar i wanna put back those build folder back to within these jobs folder .